# Equivalent of .ready() for a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect new element creation in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384398/how-to-detect-new-element-creation-in-jquery)

I have a page, which has several divs that are created by a different jQuery call. Once these divs are created, I want to make an ajax call to load some html into them. I have tried something like this (coffeescript):

```
$("#myDiv").ready ->
  alert "div ready"
```

but because the .ready function is only defined for a document, this runs immediately upon page load (before the div exists). I also tried this:

```
$("#splunk_results").ready ->
  $("#splunk_results").each ->
    alert "div ready"
```

as per the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816623/jquery-ready-fires-on-div-tag-not-in-the-page), but this seems to not load at all.

Basically, is there a simple way to execute code when a div appears?

Comment: Can you have the same jQuery that adds the divs make the ajax call and then populate them?

Comment: I could, but that would make the code more confusing (this has to happen in several different place) and creating listeners would allow for nicer compartmentalization of code

Comment: can you make use of callback? http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works#Callback_and_Functions each time you create a div call a function?

Comment: or call the ajax and only create the div on successful ajax callback?

Comment: You could look at http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers

Comment: ant, what would the element be? $. what?